# Array to string conversion error while outputting single variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a funny error while I'm trying to output a single variable assigned from database.

I'm querying a top id from database and assigning it to a variable. Here:

```
    $ID_Query = "SELECT DISTINCT MAX(pict_id) FROM picts;";
$temprID = mysql_query( $ID_Query, $Connection ) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
$myID = mysql_fetch_row( $temprID );
```

But when I'm trying to pass it to the query or simply output `$myID` I'm getting the `Array to string conversion` error.

I tried to run the query in mysql and it returns a single value. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the query returns a single value, `fetch_row` doesn't - it returns a row (who thought?) containing only one field

```
$result = mysql_fetch_row($temprID);
$myID = $result[0];
```

---

Also keep in mind that `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and hence should not be used in new code. You can use PDO or MySQLi instead. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/1557526) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Will try that. So silly not to think about it. Thank

Answer (score 1):

Currently `$myID` hold a *row* result.

You need to access...

```
$myID[0]
```

... to get the field in that row.

You could also use `mysql_result` to get the value directly from `$temprID`:

```
$myID = mysql_result($temprID, 0);
```

**Obligatory notice**: you are using deprecated `mysql_*` methods and should switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.